# Python exec(script, globals()) not showing GUI (iPyWidgets)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipywidgets, jupyterhub

Hello my fellow programmers,

I want to include a script from another file that creates a UI with iPyWidgets.
The problem is that the code will execute but nothing is shown. I am using Jupyterhub to display the button.
When I run the code on itself, the button is showing.

button_code.py

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.display import clear_output
from ipywidgets import Button, HBox, VBox, Layout, Button, Text, Textarea

widgets.Button(description = 'clear',
layout=Layout(width='20%', height='100%'))
```

call_button_script.py

```
import os
def call_script():

    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    script_fqn = os.path.join(script_dir, 'button_code.py')
    script = open(script_fqn).read()

    exec(script, globals())
```

The code is executed via the following import:

```
from call_button_script import call_script
call_script()
```

Am I missing something crucial or is there another possible mistake?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: can you provide testUI.py ? it seems your using that file instead of button_code.py

Comment: sorry I changed the name while asking this question. testUI.py is button_code.py

Comment: Why don't you ``import button_code``? Why the ``exec``?

Comment: Because the real code is much longer with many functions. It was developed over time and is not really maintainable.
It has been taken directly from a JupyterHub Script

Comment: But i`d also be open for another suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your `from call_button_script import call_script call_script()` in the same directory ? did you've seen the output on the console

Comment: Yes I can see output on the console when doing a print statement for example. Just the widget will not show. Also when I return the widget I have no possibility to let it display

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to just import the whole file.
I´ve put it in a class and initialized it all in the **init**

The GUI wasn´t showing because it was missing display() in the code